# Excel VBA Transpose and insert rows, confused

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code below to transpose and insert rows for a dataset.

Its doing mostly what i want but it inserts the rows continuously without regard to the data that is to the left of the columns.

```html
Sub TransposeInsertRows()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim iyData As Long, ixData As Long
    Dim iyResult As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rData = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range Selection...", _
                                     Title:="Transpose", _
                                     Default:=Selection.Address, _
                                     Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    If rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Only one cell selected, not enough data to transpose and insert.  Exiting Macro."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    aData = rData.Value
    ReDim aResults(1 To rData.Rows.Count * rData.Columns.Count, 1 To 2)

    For iyData = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        For ixData = 2 To UBound(aData, 2)
            If Len(Trim(aData(iyData, ixData))) > 0 Then
                iyResult = iyResult + 1
                aResults(iyResult, 1) = aData(iyData, 1)
                aResults(iyResult, 2) = aData(iyData, ixData)
            End If
        Next ixData
    Next iyData

    If iyResult = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found to transpose in selected range [" & rData.Address & "]"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    rData.Clear
    If rData.Rows.Count < iyResult Then
        rData.Offset(1).Resize(iyResult - rData.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    rData.Resize(iyResult, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

My excel data looks like the following

```html
Other Data | Data to transpose | Data to transpose |...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xyz123     |     telephone     |     123           | 312 | 123 | 334|
oij        |    faxmachine     |   129             |  22 |  3  | 
lowks      |    fridge         |     32            |   1 |  55 |  928|  239|
```

I want it to look like

```html
   Other Data | Data to transpose | Data to transpose |...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    xyz123     |    telephone     |     123  |
               |    telephone      |      312 |  
               |    telephone     |      123 |
               |    telephone      |     334  |
    oij        |    faxmachine     |   129  |      
               |    faxmachine     |    22  |
               |    faxmachine     |    3   |
    lowks      |    fridge         |     32 |     
               |    fridge         |     1  |
               |    fridge         |     55  |
               |    fridge         |     928 |
               |    fridge         |     239 |
```

Currently what I end up with is the following:

```html
 ...Other Data | Data to transpose | Data to transpose |...
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        xyz123     |    telephone     |     123  |
                   |    telepone      |      312 |  
                   |    telephone     |      123 |
                   |    telehone      |     334  |
                   |    faxmachine     |   129  |      
                   |    faxmachine     |    22  |
                   |    faxmachine     |    3   |
                   |    fridge         |     32 |     
                   |    fridge         |     1  |
                   |    fridge         |     55  |
                   |    fridge         |     928 |
                   |    fridge         |     239 |
        oij        |
        lowks      |
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My big assumption is that you can do this as a second sheet, not touching your initial data, and negating the need for inserting rows.... something like:

```
dim sws as worksheet, dws as worksheet, i as long, j as long, k as long, slr as long, dlr as long, lc as long
set sws = sheets("source")
set dws = sheets("desination")
with sws
    slr = .cells(.rows.count,2).end(xlup).row
    for i = 1 to slr 
        lc = .cells(i,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
        j = 3
        dlr = dws.cells(dws.rows.count,2).end(xlup).row+1
        dwb.cells(j,1)
        do until j = lc
            dwb.cells(dlr,2).value = .cells(i,2).value
            dwb.cells(dlr,3).value = .cells(i,j).value
            j = j+1
            dlr = dlr+1
        loop
    next i
end with
```

---

General thing I'm doing is nesting a loop to create a new table on sheets("destination") based on the data in sheets("source"), where you are looping doing value=value for the number of columns (after finding the last column on the source sheet), whcih is the do-until loop.  Once you've accounted for all of the columns (becoming rows on the second sheet), you move to the next row on the source sheet.

---

**Edit1:**

Albeit not tested, looked back and did not account for destination last row (dlr) and added that into the code.

Comment: Side note, you could also find the last column in the row (lc in my code) and use that to insert a number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your code - see added comments.

```
Sub TransposeInsertRows()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim iyData As Long, ixData As Long
    Dim iyResult As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rData = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range Selection...", _
                                     Title:="Transpose", _
                                     Default:=Selection.Address, _
                                     Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    If rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Only one cell selected, not enough data to transpose and insert.  Exiting Macro."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    aData = rData.Value
    ReDim aResults(1 To rData.Rows.Count * rData.Columns.Count, 1 To 3) 'need 3 columns, not 2
    iyResult = 1

    For iyData = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
        aResults(iyResult, 1) = aData(iyData, 1)      'xyz123 etc moe outside loop so doesn't repeat every row
        For ixData = 3 To UBound(aData, 2)                    'start at 3, as 2 is telephone etc
            If Len(Trim(aData(iyData, ixData))) > 0 Then
                aResults(iyResult, 2) = aData(iyData, 2)      'telephone etc
                aResults(iyResult, 3) = aData(iyData, ixData) 'numbers
                iyResult = iyResult + 1
            End If
        Next ixData
    Next iyData

    If iyResult = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found to transpose in selected range [" & rData.Address & "]"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    rData.Clear
    If rData.Rows.Count < iyResult Then
        rData.Offset(1).Resize(iyResult - rData.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    rData.Resize(iyResult, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you did, the thing is my data has over 100 columns, when I select what to transpose, I am selecting just the columns I want to be transposed.
But when i do that it doesn't take in consideration any of the data left of the selection.  
With your code, i ended up with 3 columns which the 1st column had the spacing that I want on all the data to the left of my selection. 

I like my final output to have 2 columns.
1 that has the telephone
2 that has the numbers

While the data is inserted taking in consideration the rest of the data to the left of my selection.

Comment: OK I assumed you selected the whole range. Allowing for that as far as I can see this produces the output you specified above.